# Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser() is returning null

Tags: admin, session

I have a custom module in my magento (version 1.5) and it's meant to load the currently logged in admin username like this in one of my controller:

```
$current_user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser();
if ($current_user) {
    $this->current_user = $current_user->getUsername();
} else {
    $this->current_user = '';
}
```

When the code runs, `$this->current_user` is empty, so I did a `var_dump($current_user); exit();` and it appears to be `null` akways (even if I am logged in).

Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: If you are logged in do you see in the admin on the top right near the serach "Logged in as USERNAME HERE"? The code that renders that section is the same as the one you use.  And one more thing? are you running your code from a frontend area or backend area?

Comment: I am running the code from the front end area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the comments...
Magento does not share the admin and frontend sessions. even if you are logged in in the backend in one tab and you use the frontend on a different tab in the same browsers, the sessions are separated. Frontend does not know about the admin session and the admin session does not know about the frontend session.
So what you are trying to achieve is not really possible.
There are workarounds, but I would not recommend them.
fronend and backend should stay separate for security reasons.
But here you go:
This should work if you you store the sessions in the db: http://www.stackoverflow.com/a/16034942/2047249

Answer (score 3):

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'adminhtml'));
//verify if the user is logged in to the backend
if(Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn()){
  echo "Admin Logged in";
}
else
{
  echo "You need to be logged in as an admin.";
}
```

Comment: The first line `Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'adminhtml'));` solved my problem. I am trying to AJAX in admin but couldn't get the custom controller to load the admin session in `preDispatch`.

Comment: The code to start the admin session is already in `preDispatch` natively so the first line is not needed. I found out that I just need to add `form_key` in the AJAX parameters to get the `preDispatch` working correctly and get the session going.

Comment: This code is not working for me

Comment: This solved my problem. I also needed to use some custom ajax controllers in admin. The first line of your solution was needed so the admin session was loaded so I could verify whether an admin is actually logged in.